# Adding a repo fails

Tags: software-installation, pantheon-terminal, software-sources

After some latest update `wget` fails! I have tried to add PPAs from PlayOnLinux's list, and the place I am to enter the passwd it always returns lines shown on the image below. Has anybody got a similar error?

[image: ERROR: This command can only be used by root.]

Comment: you have missed `sudo` in second part of command

Comment: I think you are correct Ravan. You should post him the corrected command as an answer so we can vote for it.

Comment: @elmato please use `@`before my name to notify me ;-). btw I don't understand--"You should post him the corrected command as an answer so we can vote for it"--

Comment: @elmato If i understand your comment correctly, you are suggesting me to avoid unnecessary stuff(suggestions), correct? see my edit :)

Comment: @Ravan Ah yeah. I always forget the @. I just meant that since your comment was probably the correct answer, you should post it as such so we can upvote it properly and you get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed `sudo` in second part of the command.The command should be as follows.

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

If you need more details see my revision history [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/revisions/2768/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy&paste all commands at once, you have to do it line by line.

And the more important thing is, you should **know** what these commands do, **before** you run them on your computer:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

- the first command downloads the GPG signing key of the playonlinux
  repository and adds it to the keyring.
- the second command adds the playonlinux repository to your list.
- the third command updates the list of all avaible packages of your
  repositories
- the last command finally installs playonlinux (and all of it's
  dependencies) on your computer